# Regex pattern match failure

Tags: regex, kibana, logstash-grok, grok

I am not able to match a pattern in logstash grok. Here is my data:

```
some words key[value]some words in between key[value] key[value]....some more words
```

I want to match a pattern

```
key[value] key[value]
```

i.e. two consecutive key values with space in between

I tried with `(?=\w+[.*])\s(?=\w+[.*])`, but it's not working.

I am getting the entire line with the very first key[value] and not from key[value] key[value].

Comment: give us an example so we can help you.

Comment: `\w+\[\w+\]\s\w+\[\w+\]`? Demo: https://regex101.com/r/u3O82v/1

Comment: (?=\w+\[.*\]\s\w+\[.*\]) didnt work when i tried to do look ahead

Comment: You need to escape the `[` character because it has a special meaning, that is, the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[]`.

Comment: yes, I did. somehow it is not capturing here. Also, I need to use .* between square brackets as value will have non word characters as well.

Comment: Try `(?<kv1>\w+\[[^\]\[]*])\s+(?<kv2>\w+\[[^\]\[]*])` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/FJ4ZNR/1))

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that positive lookahead is unnecessary and this expression might work:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+\[[A-Za-z0-9]+\]\s[A-Za-z0-9]+\[[A-Za-z0-9]+\]
```

#### [DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/hUO0Vg/1/)

Or:

```
(?<=[^a-z])\s(\S+\[[^]]+\])
```

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/Oc6kZ0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```regex
\S+\[[^\[]+\]
```

Means any non-space character follows by `[`, follows by any character except `[` which repeat more than one time and follows by `]`

[***Demo***](https://regex101.com/r/sqg526/4)